# Pull items from multiple nested collections from JSON in Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash, map-function

I'm using Lodash to convert one JSON structure into another. I need to extract all items from several collections that are deeply nested in the **source** structure. The destination structure is a 'flatter' version.

How do I iterate through each of the nested collections?

```
[
   {
      "regime": "Ground",
      "data": [
         { "name": AA },
         { "name": BB },
         { "name": CC }
      ]
   },
   {
      "regime": "Hover",
      "data": [
         { "name": DD },
         { "name": EE },
         { "name": FF }
      ]
   },       
   {
      "regime": "140 knots",
      "data": [
         { "name": GG },
         { "name": HH },
         { "name": II }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Destination** JSON structure:

```
[
   {
      "regime": "Ground",
      "name": AA
   },
   {
      "regime": "Ground",
      "name": BB
   },
   {
      "regime": "Ground",
      "name": CC
   },
   {
      "regime": "Hover",
      "name": DD
   },
   {
      "regime": "Hover",
      "name": EE
   },
   {
      "regime": "Hover",
      "name": FF
   },
   {
      "regime": "140 knots",
      "name": GG
   },
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
o = [
   {
      "regime": "Ground",
      "data": [
         { "name": 'AA' },
         { "name": 'BB' },
         { "name": 'CC' }
      ]
   },
   {
      "regime": "Hover",
      "data": [
         { "name": 'DD' },
         { "name": 'EE' },
         { "name": 'FF' }
      ]
   },       
   {
      "regime": "140 knots",
      "data": [
         { "name": 'GG' },
         { "name": 'HH' },
         { "name": 'II' }
      ]
   }
];

newO = _(o).map((e)=> {
  return e.data.map((d)=> {
    return {
      regime: e.regime,
      name: d.name
    }
  })
}).flatten().value();

console.log(newO);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Where `o` is your object

Comment: Love this solution. Totally got the hang of it now following this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

One way to acehive this is

```js
var input = [
   {
      "regime": "Ground",
      "data": [
         { "name": "AA" },
         { "name": "BB" },
         { "name": "CC" }
      ]
   },
   {
      "regime": "Hover",
      "data": [
         { "name": "DD" },
         { "name": "EE" },
         { "name": "FF" }
      ]
   },       
   {
      "regime": "140 knots",
      "data": [
         { "name": "GG" },
         { "name": "HH" },
         { "name": "II" }
      ]
   }
];


var result = _.flatten(_.map(input, function(it){
 return _.map(it.data, function(subIT){
   return { regime: it.regime, name: subIT.name};
 });
}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```